# Cannot open include file "windows.h" No such file or directory

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to build a project which contain several C# projects and one C++ project in VS 2013.

But during build the above error is shown, then i googled the error and tried several things but unable to fix the issue.

**Things i have tried:**

1) Added Window 10 SDK's Include directory to the Additional Include Directories 
   in C/C++ Configuration properties.

2) Added  Window 10 SDK's Lib directory to the Additional Library Directories into the Linker.

3) Making sure that include file is "windows.h" instead of "Windows.h".

> Path of Windows.h file present locally in SDK directory is

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\um

Does any  have any idea how can i fix this ?

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: The error you are asking about clearly has nothing to do with any of the C# projects, since C# doesn't have include files. Tag removed. It's likely your question is a duplicate in the [tag:c++] tag, since getting include paths correct is such a basic issue when using C++, but you'll have to wait for someone who frequents that tag to track down the duplicate. In the meantime, consider RTM.

Comment: See posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415521/cannot-open-include-file-with-visual-studio

Comment: @jdweng I have tried all the solution which are present in the link but none of them works in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 can't find windows.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410631/visual-studio-2017-cant-find-windows-h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the project properties -> Configuration Properties -> General

then Change Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2013- Windows XP(v120_xp).

This is what worked for me.