# Getting " Cannot open source file "pugixml.hpp" " error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

When I try to build solution in visual studio I get an error saying :

*Cannot open source file "pugixml.hpp"*  along with some other errors , such as :
*Cannot open include file: 'cereal/types/list.hpp': No such file or directory.*

I downloaded the code onto my local machine from a SVN repository and the solution is an integration of C++ and C#. Could it be due to my limited access to the repo or not.
Thanks

I looked it up on the internet and I tried going to the project properties and adding the directory manually but I didn't work. I am not professional , so maybe I haven't done this properly.

Comment: Looks like that project has another dependency to the [pugixml library](https://pugixml.org/) and you need to download and install that as well.

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, downloading an external library needs to include its library directory and various header file directories.

If a dll is used, this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170#create-a-client-app-that-uses-the-dll) explains how to use the dll.

Regarding `Cannot open source file "...hpp"`, you could refer to the method in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415521/cannot-open-include-file-with-visual-studio).